# Select from table with values separated by comma

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I am having trouble with my query since I really don't know what to write. I want to get value from the database from my data which is inside an array separated by comma.
Let's say I have this method on my controller

```
query_array = array(
        'tags' => explode("%2C", $this->input->get('tags'))
    );
```

Then currently I have this query on my model.

```
if(strlen($query_array['title'])) {
        $this->db->select("
        si.song_info_file_name AS filename, 
        si.song_info_revised_file_name AS revised_filename, 
        si.song_info_original_title AS title, 
        a.artist_name AS artist,
        si.song_info_id AS songinfoid, 
        array_to_string(array_agg(c.composer_name),'/') AS composer,
        array_to_string(array_agg(p.publisher_name),'/') AS publisher, 
        array_to_string(array_agg(st.tag_name),',') AS tags"
    );
    $this->db->from('song_info si');
    $this->db->join('original_artist a', 'si.artist_id = a.artist_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('composer c', 'si.composer_id = c.composer_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('publisher p', 'si.publisher_id = p.publisher_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('song_info_tags sit', 'si.song_info_id = sit.song_info_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('song_tags st', 'st.tag_id = sit.tag_id', 'left');

    $this->db->like('LOWER(a.artist_name)', strtolower($query_array['title']));
    $this->db->group_by(array("si.song_info_id", "a.artist_name", "c.composer_name" , "p.publisher_name" ));

    $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

The value of `'tags' => explode("%2C", $this->input->get('tags'))` is `Array ( [0] => 4,10,11,14 )` if I already explode it. my question now is that how would I be able to add this to my `select LIKE` criteria? for example `LIKE tag_id =` from the result of the array. I really need some help since I'm stuck with this one for kinda while now.

Comment: $select= "Select movie_name from movie where tag_id in (";

$len=count($explode_array);
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
{
   $select.=$explode_array[$i].","; #appending 4,10,11,14 one by one
}

$select=rtrim($select,","); #trimming extra comma
$select.=")";

Comment: Please post your table structure with relationship of each other and expected output of your query.